# Receives an object (parameter) and returns an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been trying to receive an object as a parameter and return it as an array but no luck. I don't see why it could be any problems in the code. I might be lost at this point or just completely out of the logic.

```
function att(testobj) {
    var q = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < testobj.length ; i++){
        q += testobj[i] + " ";
    }
    return q;
}

var obj1= {
    Big: 10,
    low: 5
};

var attObj1= att(obj1);
console.log(attObj1); 

var obj2= {
    a: 10,
    b: 20,
    c: 30
};

var attObj2= att(obj2);
console.log(attObj2);
```

I did try as in the code do a for-loop where it check each array length and sort it by using  `q += testobj[i]` but I'm not getting any results. Just a blank console log.

Comment: Thank you Filburt for the edit :)

Comment: `testobj.length`: objects do not have a `length` property the same way that arrays do. If you want to iterate over them, use `Object.keys`.

Comment: please add the wanted output.

Comment: @NinaScholz I want it to print out ["Big", "low"] and ["a", "b", "c"]

Comment: 1. use each 2. you are creating a string not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article may help you [object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // console: ['0', '1', '2']

var obj = { key0: 'value-0', key1: 'value-1', key2: 'value-2' };
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // console: ['key0', 'key1', 'key2']
```

Comment: Yes ! Someone just posted it aswell! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the keys and return the joind value.

Method used:

- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for getting all keys from the object,
- [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) convert an array to a string with the given string as glue.

```js
function att(testobj) {
  return Object.keys(testobj).join(', ');  
}

var obj1= {
    Big: 10,
    low: 5
};

var attObj1= att(obj1);
console.log(attObj1); 

var obj2= {
    a: 10,
    b: 20,
    c: 30
};

var attObj2= att(obj2);
console.log(attObj2);
```

Comment: Oh, Could you please explain Object.keys(testobj).map(function (k) means? I quite didnt understand just that part :) If you have time over of course!

Comment: `.map(function (k) {  return k; })` unnecessary step - it's going to return the same array anyway. The only benefit is that it'd be copied but `Object.keys` already constructs a new one, so no benefit in that.

Comment: That was quite smart I would say. Not that I would do by myself. But thanks! Always good to learn extra !:)

Answer (score 1):

Although an `Array` is technically an `Object`, one difference is that they can be iterated over.

So for example you can do:

```js
var someArray = ['some', 'value', 'here'];

for (var i = 0; i <= someArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(someArray[i]);
}
```

However, with an object you cannot as it doesn't contain the iterate functionality.

If you want to iterate through an `Object` and an `Array` interchangeably, you need to consider using a method that supports both.

For example:

```js
function iterateOver(obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    console.log('Key', k, 'Value', obj[k]);
  }
}

var someArray = ['some', 'value', 'here'];
var someObject = {
  some: 'value',
  another: 'great_value'
};

iterateOver(someArray);
iterateOver(someObject);
```

Comment: Ohhhhh okay! Now I get it! That was quite good explanation I would say. Now I understand it all! Thank you Joseph! :)